# M2 how to add a custom css only to a module override?

Tags: magento2, overrides, less-css

I need to apply this code to checkout page:

```
.header-wrapper-content.sticky-menu.active{display:none;}
.hdmx__contact-button.hdmx__contact-button-right{display:none;}
```

This hide the sticky menu and the float contact us module from the checkout.

How can I apply this only to the checkout page?

I already tried to create
"app/design/frontend/your-store/your-theme/Magento_Checkout/web/css/source/_extend.less"

where "_extend.less" file contains the CSS above, but in this way, the style is applied to the whole site.

I need to have that code only on during checkout.

Comment: you can only achieve this by specifying your selector

Comment: Could you please be more specific? I have not understood your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
body[class^="checkout"] {
    .header-wrapper-content.sticky-menu.active,
    .hdmx__contact-button.hdmx__contact-button-right {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

This will only apply the CSS selector to pages that come from actions within the checkout-module

Comment: It works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

**1.If your have extend your theme from Luma theme then copy below file,**

```
From : \vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\Magento_Checkout\web\css\source\module\checkout\_checkout.less

to 
\app\design\frontend\Package\theme\Magento_Checkout\web\css\source\module\_checkout.less
```

add your custom css code into this file

**2.By adding your custom css file**

You can add your custom css file for checkout page only with below step 
   Create custom_checkout.css file into your theme Path

/app/design/frontend/Package/theme/web/css/custom_checkout.css

```
Call your custom css in <head> tag of the  XML layout handles of the checkout page
```

File:Path : \app\design\frontend\Package\theme\Magento_Checkout\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml

Put below code ino above XML file.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
            <head>
                   <css src="css/custom_checkout.css" />
            </head>
    </page>
```

Comment: The point 2 is not working, the custom CSS is applied to the whole site, home page too.. I'm going to test the point 1 and let you know.

Comment: Nor the point 1 working, it apply the styles all over the website.